# What is a "good" way to trigger function(s) of connecting "chambers" (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, triggers, grid

I've got the following problem I need to solve:

Pretend you have a raster/grid of 5x5 filled with a's and b's:

```
a a a b a 
a b a a a 
a a a a a 
b b b b b 
a a b a a
```

When I trigger (click) one of these "chambers" I would like to change the value of that chamber and all connecting chambers containing the same value (horizontally and vertically).

Let's say I want to change the values to y.

When I trigger (click) the "a" on position [2][1] (third position second row) I want the raster/grid to look like this:

```
y y y b y 
y b y y y 
y y y y y 
b b b b b 
a a b a a
```

Notice the a's on the bottom. They should not have been changed (they did not connect).

What is the best way to handle this?
Is using a multidimensional array good enough? Or should I use a hashmap/arraylist? Does every "chamber" need to contain references to the connecting chambers?

What would be a "beautiful", performant way to do this?

Comment: are you doing minesweeper?

Comment: yes. I am doing minesweeper. It already *works* but I would like to see different solutions

Answer (score 1):

> Is using a multidimensional array good enough?

Multidimensional array is good enough for this problem and your knowledge.

> ```
> Does every "chamber" need to contain references to the connecting chambers?
> ```

No it doesn't to have any reference, since you can calculate position of other cells by adding/subtracting position of the current cell.

> What would be a "beautiful", performant way to do this?

Just start to work on it. Try to answer questions that rise when you are doing.